# Declaring a multidimensional array in a single statement

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array, matrix

Let's say I want to create a matrix `A` with dimensions 3×4×4 with a single statement (*i.e* one equality, without any concatenations), something like this:

```
%// This is one continuous row
A = [ [ [3 3 4 4], [8 11 8 7], [4 4 6 7], [4 7 6 6] ];  ...
      [ [3 2 4 2], [9 6 4 12], [4 3 3 4], [5 10 7 3] ]; ...
      [ [2 2 1 2], [3 3 3 2], [2 2 2 2],  [3 3 3 3] ] ]
```

Answer (score 6):

The [concatenation operator `[]`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/creating-and-concatenating-matrices.html) will only work in 2 dimensions, like `[a b]` to concatenate horizontally or `[a; b]` to concatenate vertically. To create [matrices with higher dimensions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/multidimensional-arrays.html) you can use the [`reshape`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) function, or initialize a matrix of the size you want and then fill it with your values. For example, you could do this:

```
A = reshape([...], [3 4 4]);  % Where "..." is what you have above
```

Or this:

```
A = zeros(3, 4, 4);  % Preallocate the matrix
A(:) = [...];        % Where "..." is what you have above
```

Comment: The second one is what I did. Thank you very much

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`cat`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cat.html) to "layer" 2-D matrices along the third dimension, for example:

```
A = cat(3, ones(4), 2*ones(4), 3*ones(4));
```

Technically this is concatenation, but it's still only one assignment.

[image: CATLAB]